# How do I create a template class that can accept any type that satisfies std::forward_iterator<T> in the constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am making a circular iterator class that behaves like a forward iterator, except it loops back to the beginning after reaching the end of a range.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct CircularIterator
{
    CircularIterator(T* begin, T* end);

    // Omitted overloaded operators

    T* mBegin;  // Points to beginning of range
    T* mIter;   // Current item
    T* mEnd;    // Points to end of range
};
```

There is no conversion from an STL iterator (e.g., `std::vector<int>::iterator>`) to a raw pointer (`T*`). The following code compiles with an error:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
CircularIterator<int> iter(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

```
error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
```

**How do I create a template class that can accept any type that satisfies `std::forward_iterator<T>` in the constructor?** I would like to avoid creating a new template instance for each iterator type that is used (e.g., new `CircularIterator` for `std::array<T>::iterator` and `std::deque<T>::iterator`.)

Any advice would be appriciated. I'm definately at the far end of my template/concept knowledge and look forward to any resources to learn more. Thank you.

Comment: An alternative constructor that would accomplish my goal: `template <typename Range> explicit CircularIterator(Range& range);` which initializes `mBegin`, `mIter`, and `mEnd` with the STL `data()` function to get a raw pointer.

Comment: There are 3 containers in `std` that have a `data()` member function: `std::vector`, `std::array`,  `std::basic_string` (plus the not-a-container `std::string_view`). Either `CircularIterator` isn't usable with *most* containers, or you have to have the iterator type as part of the template.

Answer (score 3):

You can constrain the template parameter `I` of `CircularIterator` must satisfy [`std::forward_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator), e.g.

```
#include <iterator>

template <std::forward_iterator I>
struct CircularIterator
{
    CircularIterator() = default;
    CircularIterator(I begin, I end);

    // Omitted overloaded operators

    I mBegin;  // Points to beginning of range
    I mIter;   // Current item
    I mEnd;    // Points to end of range
};
```

Note that you need to provide a default constructor for `CircularIterator` because `std::forward_iterator` requires a default constructor.

Comment: I develop for an embedded project with 256K of memory, so I cannot use this solution because it generates a new template instantiation for every type of iterator. As I understand it, a CircularIterator constructed from a vector and a CircularIterator constructed from an array would be different classes contributing to code bloat.

Comment: @Matt if you can't afford to have a different type for each iterator type, you can't be generic

Answer (score 2):

Forward iterators don't have to be iterators to a contigous range so `T* mBegin` isn't suitable. You could instead store the iterators themselves. Here's one possible way using SFINAE with `is_base_of_v` and `forward_iterator_tag`:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <class It, class EndIt,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<
              std::forward_iterator_tag,
              typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category>,int> = 0>
struct CircularIterator {
    CircularIterator(It begin, EndIt end)
        : mBegin(begin), mIter(begin), mEnd(end) {}

    It mBegin;   // Points to beginning of range
    It mIter;    // Current item
    EndIt mEnd;  // Points to end of range
};
```

If you really want to store `T*` to get fewer instantiations of the class template, you would have to require the iterator to be a `contiguous_iterator` instead:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct CircularIterator {
    CircularIterator(std::contiguous_iterator auto begin,
                     std::contiguous_iterator auto end)
        : mBegin(begin != end ? &*begin : nullptr),
          mIter(mBegin),
          mEnd(std::next(mBegin, std::distance(begin, end))) {}

    T* mBegin;  // Points to beginning of range
    T* mIter;   // Current item
    T* mEnd;    // Points to end of range
};

// deduction guide:
template<class It, class EndIt>
CircularIterator(It, EndIt) ->
        CircularIterator<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>;
```

... and used like in your example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};

    // specifying `<int>` is optional with the added deduction guide:
    CircularIterator iter(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K59srj3PM)

Comment: I don't think I can use this solution because it would create a new template instantiation for each kind of iterator. This code is for an embedded project.

Comment: @Matt It would create one instance for all `vector<int>`s. If you have a `vector<double>` even the `vector<double>::iterator` will be different and the whole `vector<T>` template instantiation will be doubled. Instances of this iterator template will not be very big in comparison.

Comment: @Matt ... but added an option that may require fewer instantiations

Comment: `&*end` is UB, as is `&*begin` for an empty container

Comment: @Caleth No, `&*end` does not dereference the end iterator. It takes the address one step after the last element - but does not read it. There was a big post about this some time ago. Concensus was that it was ok.

Comment: It absolutely *does* dereference the iterator named `end`. Try it with msvc's debug-mode iterators

Comment: @Caleth `-fsanitize=address,undefined -fanalyzer` doesn't report anything fishy. I wonder if MSVC's debug-mode iterator really does the right thing? It reports a problem for `mBegin(&begin[0]), mIter(mBegin), mEnd(mBegin + std::distance(begin, end))` too (with the same `vector<int>` with 3 elements) which is clearly perfectly ok.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: It could be attempting to guard against possible bad use.  `std::deque` also provides a random access iterator, but the above construct would not be safe for it, and the debug mode iterator might be attempting to hide that.  While it's valid for `std::vector`, I wouldn't trust it beyond the types that were considered contiguous iterators.  (such as vector and std::array provide).

Comment: @DaveS True. I fixed that.

Comment: @Caleth I made a new version. MSVC with `/EHsc /MDd` still complains. I don't see why it should.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're thinking about pointers. Iterators have a specific (and different) precondition, and it's "don't dereference `end`".

Comment: @PasserBy I was thinking that it wasn't actually dereferencing the end iterator but that's irrelevant after the edit since the value of the pointer `mEnd` is now calculated differently.  I don't see what could make it have UB. MSVC complains even if I make it `mEnd(begin != end ? std::next(mBegin, std::distance(begin, end)) : nullptr)`

Comment: @Caleth I got tricked by the MSVC exit status in compiler explorer. I now tried the above version in VS2022 in debug mode and it works just fine. Sorry for the confusion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your desires are in direct competition

> any type that satisfies std::forward_iterator in the constructor?

> avoid creating a new template instance for each iterator type that is used

Pick one of those. There is no common type between `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `std::deque<int>::iterator` for you to have as the data members of `CircularIterator<int>`.

In a memory constrained environment, why are you even mixing `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::deque` in the first place? Those are much larger templates. If the only container you use is `std::vector`, what does it matter whether you hold `std::vector<int>::iterator`s or `int *` in `CircularIterator<int>`?

Comment: To answer your unrelated question about containers, I'm using specialized containers which are embedded-safe. However, unit tests may use `std::vector` or `std::deque`

Comment: @Matt it's not unrelated. If you are worried about the code size of a handful of instantiations of a ~20 line template, why have more than one container type in the first place?